# Does the empty set being separable lead to the absurd that every space is separable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm the book Linear functional analysis by Rynne and Youngson, Second edition gives a summary of  topology of metric spaces concepts

Definition 1.41.

A set $X$ is countable if it contains either a finite number of elements or infinitely many elements and can be written in the form $X = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$; in the latter case X is said to be countably infinite.

**A metric space $(M, d)$ is separable if it contains a countable, dense subset.
The empty set $\phi$ is regarded as separable**.

**Then I started wondering if the empty set being separable was consistent**:
Since $\phi$ is separable, and the only set contained in it is $\phi$ itself, it must be dense (I can also proof that arguing that the empty set is always closed in any topology, so it is clearly equal to its closure , hence dense in itself) and countable.  Since any space S contains the empty set, I have found that S contains a dense countable set, so by definition of separable space, S is separable. S was arbitrary, then any space is separable.

**This can't be true,cleary non-separable spaces do exist, but then what is wrong with my proof?** It seems to  me that declaring the empty set as separable is inconsistent. Perhaps I am missunderstanding the statement or I am supposed to assume something

Comment: "Since any space contains the empty set, then any space is separable." What exactly is your argument here? Yes, the empty set is dense (!) in the empty set (!) but the empty set is not dense in any other arbitrary set. A set $A$ is always dense as a subset of $A$, but that does not imply that $A$ is dense in some superset $B \supset A$.

Comment: @FlorianR. I added more to explain myself better, basically what I think is that since any arbitrary set contains the empty set, which is dense and countable, any space is separable

Comment: @J.C.VegaO what's the definition of a dense set? A proper closed subset in a topological space can't be dense. So, empty set can't be dense in any topological space where the underlying set is non empty.$\overline {\emptyset}=\emptyset \neq  X$

Comment: Think of it this way: the definition of "dense" involves two sets. A set $A \subset B$ is dense in $B$ if the closure of $A$ is $B$. That $(M,d)$ contains a dense subset means that there exists a set $A \subset M$ such that the closure of $A$ is $M$. In your argument, you say that $S$ contains a dense subset (namely the empty set), but this denseness of the empty set is not relative to $S$, i.e. you apply the definition of denseness with $A=B=\emptyset$, not $A=\emptyset$ and $B=S$.

Comment: Any set is dense in itself.

Comment: What's so special about the empty set? By the same argument, the fact that a one-element space is separable implies that every (nonempty) space is separable!!!

Comment: I get it, I was applying incorrectly the definiton of dense sets, as Florian R pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space $X$ is seperable if it contains a countable subset $A$ such that $\overline{A}=X$; in other words A is dense in $X$.

Clearly if $X$ is non empty then the empty set is never dense in $X$.